# I am unable to insert data from Android to Localhost

Tags: php, android

I created `PHP` script in a file and I am unable to get data from `PHP`

Below is my `PHP` script file :

```
function storeUser($name, $email, $password ,$phone) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, phone ,password, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $email, $phone, $password);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

My Android code is perfectly correct, and I send the parameters. But I can not put the parameter with function into the localhost

Please tell me if you know my problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I can not put the parameter with function into the localhost". Does it mean that they come empty? How is the function called? Please, give a bit more context, directly in the question.

Comment: Please past more code

Comment: Now that I notice, your query expects 6 parameters, yet you only pass 4

Comment: That may be just to show us as an example

Comment: @UmangBurman examples that don't reproduce the problem OP's having are not really useful. The site rules say we need a minimal, *complete* and *verifiable* example

Comment: I've added 6 s but the problem persists

Comment: @JacksUtil I'm not talking only about the `s`s. Where are `password` and `created_at`? If they are created with a default value remove them (and the respective `s`s) from the query (and the `bind_param` call)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I know what the rules say, that is why I said "May be" if you can read. Because many of us may not know about it.

Comment: "Because many of us may not know about it" frankly, that's a poor excuse. Also "if you can read" is unnecessarily rude. I've kept my composure, I expect others to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pay attention to the code you write

In the bind_param section you must delete one of the "s"
Only the number of received parameters from the Android side should be use s.
change

```
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $email, $phone, $password);
```

to

```
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $phone, $password);
```